# Application Insights - How to search by some properties in custom dimension

Tags: azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center, azure-data-explorer

I am using mobile application i.e Appcenter for recording customevents AzureLogportal.

I am trying to fetch the records by using custom query.
Inside `customDimensions` Object of array i.e Properties i stored.
`Properties = {"1":"Studentname","101":"id","John":"Title"}`

I am trying to fetch all the records for title : John in the properties.
Query  i tried is :

```
customEvents
|where customDimensions.Properties.TopicTitle == "John"
```

But it dont give any result.Please help.

Answer (score 2):

if `Properties` within `customDimensions` is a property bag, then the bottom note in this document should have the answer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction

> **Notes**
>
> It is somewhat common to have a JSON string describing a property bag in which one of the "slots" is another JSON string. For example:

```
let d='{"a":123, "b":"{\\"c\\":456}"}';
print d
```

> In such cases, it is not only necessary to invoke `parse_json` twice, but also to make sure that in the second call, `tostring` will be used. Otherwise, the second call to `parse_json` will simply pass-on the input to the output as-is, because its declared type is `dynamic`:

```
let d='{"a":123, "b":"{\\"c\\":456}"}';
print d_b_c=parse_json(tostring(parse_json(d).b)).c
```